# CASE statement returning multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the below case statement to join two tables, however looks like the CASE statement isn't working currently. I expect for it to match the REVENUE from ORDERS table with the LIMIT in the BUCKET table and return only the bucket under which the REVENUE falls. Rights now it returns 4 rows with wrong buckets for some reason.

In the sample data below, I expect for it to return Bucket 3.

*Could someone please help point what is wrong here.*
**Thanks so much in advance.**

```
select o.Org, o.REVENUE,b.BUCKET,
CASE
                       WHEN  o.REVENUE <= b.LIMIT and BUCKET = 'Bucket 1' 
                           THEN '1'
                       WHEN o.REVENUE <= b.LIMIT and BUCKET = 'Bucket 2'  
                           THEN '2'
                       WHEN   0.REVENUE <= b.LIMIT and BUCKET = 'Bucket 3'
                           THEN '3'
                       ELSE '4'
                   END AS DERIVED_BUCKET
from ORDERS o
inner join BUCKET_TABLE b
on o.Org = b.Org
where ID  = '12345'
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a `CASE` **expression** not a `Case` (`Switch`) statement. T-SQL does not support the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is logic issue in the code it will fire all case statements  you have to have some lower bound and upper bound so issue can be fixed ie lag or lead or have the range in the table .

```
create table ORDERS
(id int,org  varchar(20),REVENUE int)

insert into ORDERS
(id ,org  ,REVENUE )

select 
12345 as id ,'org1'  as org , 1200 REVENUE 


create table BUCKET_TABLE
(org  varchar(20),BUCKET  varchar(20) , limit int )

insert into BUCKET_TABLE
(org  ,BUCKET,limit)

select 
'org1'  as org , 'BUCKET_1' as BUCKET  ,100 as limit
union
select 
'org1'  as org , 'BUCKET_2' as BUCKET  , 1000 limit
union
select 
'org1'  as org , 'BUCKET_3' as BUCKET , 5000 limit 
union
select 
'org1'  as org , 'BUCKET_4' as BUCKET , 10000 limit 

select o.Org, o.REVENUE,b.BUCKET 
,
CASE
                       WHEN ( o.REVENUE < b.LIMIT and 
                       b.BUCKET = 'BUCKET_1' )
                           THEN '1'
                       WHEN   b.rn < o.REVENUE  and  o.REVENUE  <= b.LIMIT and
                        b.BUCKET = 'BBUCKET_2'  THEN '2'
                       WHEN  b.rn < o.REVENUE  and  b.BUCKET = 'BUCKET_3'
                           THEN '3'
                        WHEN  b.rn < o.REVENUE  and  b.BUCKET = 'BUCKET_4'
                           THEN '4'
                   END AS DERIVED_BUCKET
from ORDERS o

inner join 
(select * , LAG(limit) over (partition by org  order by limit asc ) as rn  from BUCKET_TABLE)b
on o.Org = b.Org
where ID  = '12345'
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Use `cross apply` for this:

```
select o.Org, o.REVENUE, b.BUCKET
from ORDERS o cross apply
     (select top (1) b.*
      from bucket_table b
      where  o.Org = b.Org and b.limit >= o.revenue
      order by b.limit desc
     ) b
where ID = '12345';
```

You can also use `lag()` so you can use a proper `join`:

```
select o.*, b.*
from orders o join
     (select b.*, lag(limit) over (partition by org order by limit) as prev_limit
      from buckets b
     ) b
     on b.order = o.org and
        (o.revenue > b.prev_limit or b.prev_limit is null) and
        (o.revenue <= b.limit)
```

Comment: That suggests that either `limit` or `revenue` are an `nvarchar` @Newbie . I *hope* not. Also, `float` is normally a poor data type choice for monetary value.

Comment: Well there's your problem, @Newbie . You need to fix your data types (and data), as you clearly have a value in there now that isn't even a valid number.

Comment: The fact you are getting the error "Error converting data type nvarchar to float" suggests that you have invalid values, @Newbie . Store numerical data in numerical data types. `nvarchar` is *not* a "one type fits all" data type.

Comment: @Gordon . how can i get the value of DERIVED_BUCKET as in my original query? could you please let me know.

Comment: Also I do not understand why it doesnt work with my original CASE statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216879/discussion-between-newbie-and-larnu).

Comment: @Newbie . . . Your "derived" bucket appears to be pretty much the same as the `bucket` in the `buckets` table.  I would recommend using the value in the data.

Comment: *"t doesnt work with my original CASE statement."* It's still a  `CASE` expression; there are no `Case` statements in T-SQL.